# JPA and Hibernate - Criteria vs. JPQL or HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

What are the pros and cons of using [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html) or [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html)? The Criteria API is a nice object-oriented way to express queries in Hibernate, but sometimes Criteria Queries are more difficult to understand/build than HQL.

When do you use Criteria and when HQL? What do you prefer in which use cases? Or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: The right answer would be 'depends on the use case'.

Comment: Definition of an opinion-based question, yet people haven't taken the opportunity to close it ... as per the site FAQ

Answer (score 220, accepted):

I mostly prefer Criteria Queries for dynamic queries. For example it is much easier to add some ordering dynamically or leave some parts (e.g. restrictions) out depending on some parameter.

On the other hand I'm using HQL for static and complex queries, because it's much easier to understand/read HQL. Also, HQL is a bit more powerful, I think, e.g. for different join types.

Comment: Also, although Criteria looks a little more type-safe, the only thing that can make you feel safe is testing.

Comment: Are there any good examples which show why HQL is better than criteria api in certain cases ? I read the end of one blog, but understood nothing. Would appreciate it if you could help. Thanks. Link - http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

Comment: All the reasons above - I also prefer Criteria to HQL because it's safer to the programmer, diminishing coding errors - compilation on the HQL string is not validated.

Comment: However, there's the issue of retrieving distinct entities whilst paginating. When doing this I'd pick HQL to avoid issues...

Comment: using criteria query with a metamodel for the column names helps during refactoring to not break anything and with a simple command from a modern IDE to rename all the occurrences in the code.

Answer (score 93):

There is a difference in terms of performance between HQL and criteriaQuery, everytime you fire a query using criteriaQuery, it creates a new alias for the table name which does not reflect in the last queried cache for any DB. This leads to an overhead of compiling the generated SQL, taking more time to execute.

Regarding fetching strategies [[http://www.hibernate.org/315.html]](http://www.hibernate.org/315.html)

> - Criteria respects the laziness settings in your mappings and guarantees that what you want loaded is loaded. This means one Criteria query might result in several SQL immediate SELECT statements to fetch the subgraph with all non-lazy mapped associations and collections. If you want to change the "how" and even the "what", use setFetchMode() to enable or disable outer join fetching for a particular collection or association. Criteria queries also completely respect the fetching strategy (join vs select vs subselect).
> - HQL respects the laziness settings in your mappings and guarantees that what you want loaded is loaded. This means one HQL query might result in several SQL immediate SELECT statements to fetch the subgraph with all non-lazy mapped associations and collections. If you want to change the "how" and even the "what", use LEFT JOIN FETCH to enable outer-join fetching for a particular collection or nullable many-to-one or one-to-one association, or JOIN FETCH to enable inner join fetching for a non-nullable many-to-one or one-to-one association. HQL queries do not respect any fetch="join" defined in the mapping document.

Comment: Just pointing out to anyone browsing. that this answer is from 2008. this may not be the case anymore. http://dimovelev.blogspot.com/2015/02/performance-pitfalls-hibernate-criteria.html

Answer (score 42):

Criteria is an object-oriented API, while HQL means string concatenation. That means all of the benefits of object-orientedness apply:

1. All else being equal, the OO version is somewhat less prone to error. Any old string could get appended into the HQL query, whereas only valid Criteria objects can make it into a Criteria tree. Effectively, the Criteria classes are more constrained.
2. With auto-complete, the OO is more discoverable (and thus easier to use, for me at least). You don't necessarily need to remember which parts of the query go where; the IDE can help you
3. You also don't need to remember the particulars of the syntax (like which symbols go where). All you need to know is how to call methods and create objects.

Since HQL is very much like SQL (which most devs know very well already) then these "don't have to remember" arguments don't carry as much weight. If HQL was more different, then this would be more importatnt.

Comment: These arguments don't hold water (with respect to HQL). It does not have to involve string concatenation. That the OO version is less prone to errors is unsubstantiated. It is equally prone to errors but of a different kind. The effort of knowing what methods to call is not that much different from knowing what symbols to call in HQL (I mean, seriously, we are not solving PDEs here.)

Comment: Are there any good examples which show why HQL is better than criteria api in certain cases ? I read the end of one blog, but understood nothing. Would appreciate it if you could help. Thanks. Link - http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

Comment: HQL named queries are compiled on deploy time and at this point missing fields (maybe for bad refactors?) are detected. I think this make code more resilient and in fact less error prone than criteria.

Comment: Auto-complete in Criteria is pretty much useless because the properties are just strings.

Answer (score 37):

I usually use Criteria when I don't know what the inputs will be used on which pieces of data.  Like on a search form where the user can enter any of 1 to 50 items and I don't know what they will be searching for.  It is very easy to just append more to the criteria as I go through checking for what the user is searching for.  I think it would be a little more troublesome to put an HQL query in that circumstance.  HQL is great though when I know exactly what I want.

Comment: This is a good comment.  We currently build very large HQL strings for a search form that contains many different objects through joins.  Looks ugly.  Going to see if a Criteria can clean that up.  Interesting...

Comment: Thanks. This is an excellent example. Can you please give me some more ?

Comment: best explanation @Arthur Thomas

Answer (score 33):

HQL is much easier to read, easier to debug using tools like the Eclipse Hibernate plugin, and easier to log. Criteria queries are better for building dynamic queries where a lot of the behavior is determined at runtime.  If you don't know SQL, I could understand using Criteria queries, but overall I prefer HQL if I know what I want upfront.

Answer (score 30):

### Criteria API

Criteria API is better suited for dynamically generated queries. So, if you want to add WHERE clause filters, JOIN clauses, or vary the ORDER BY clause or the projection columns, then the Criteria API can help you generate the query dynamically in a way that also prevents SQL Injection attacks.

On the other hand, Criteria queries are less expressive and can even lead to very complicated and inefficient SQL queries.

### JPQL and HQL

JPQL is the JPA standard entity query language while HQL extends JPQL and adds some Hibernate-specific features.

JPQL and HQL are very expressive and resemble SQL. Unlike Criteria API, JPQL and HQL make it easy to predict the underlying SQL query that's generated by the JPA provider. It's also much easier to review one's HQL queries than Criteria ones.

It's worth noting that selecting entities with JPQL or Criteria API makes sense if you need to modify them. Otherwise, a DTO projection is a much better choice.

### Conclusion

If you don't need to vary the entity query structure, then use JPQL or HQL. If you need to change the filtering or sorting criteria or change the projection, then use Criteria API.

However, just because you are using JPA or Hibernate, it doesn't mean you should not use native SQL. SQL queries are very useful and JPQL and Criteria API are not a replacement for SQL.

Comment: could you please look at my problem [How to write HQL JOIN query for multiple table's selected Columns using Constructor In The Select Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47726605/3425489) **thank you**

Comment: have been following your ansers/blogs for long.. gr8 stuff. +1. if you got time - would you mind helping with this [Criteria API and JPQL API with GROUP BY and CONCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129333/criteria-api-and-jpql-api-with-group-by-and-concat/73163002#73163002)

Comment: when it comes to Native SQL vs Criteria, seems there are limitation when we get to native functions usage from hibernate. Refered this article by you->but this too does not address the `DISTINCT / ORDER BY / SEPERATOR` Issue - https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/. Could you enlighted us on the limitations on sof post [Criteria API and JPQL API with GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129333/criteria-api-and-jpql-api-with-group-by-and-concat)

Comment: Vlad - glad to see you response. NP. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Criteria are the only way to specify natural key lookups that take advantage of the special optimization in the second level query cache.  HQL does not have any way to specify the necessary hint.

You can find some more info here:

- http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/

Answer (score 23):

Criteria Api is one of the good concept of Hibernate. according to my view these are the few point by which we can make difference between **HQL** and **Criteria Api**

1. HQL is to perform both select and non-select operations on the data,  but Criteria is only for selecting the data, we cannot perform non-select operations using criteria.
2. HQL is suitable for executing Static Queries, where as Criteria is suitable for executing Dynamic Queries
3. HQL doesn’t support **pagination** concept, but we can achieve pagination with Criteria.
4. Criteria used to take more time to execute than HQL.
5. With Criteria we are safe with **SQL Injection** because of its dynamic query generation but in HQL as your queries are either fixed or parametrized, there is no safe from SQL Injection

Comment: Couple of points

Pagination is there in HQL: you can use `limit offset:rows`

In hql you can avoid sql injection using `setParameter`

Answer (score 15):

To use the best of both worlds, the expressivity and conciseness of HQL and the dynamic nature of Criteria consider using [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com).

Querydsl supports JPA/Hibernate, JDO, SQL and Collections.

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, so this answer is biased.

Answer (score 14):

For me Criteria is a quite easy to Understand and making Dynamic queries. But the flaw i say so far is that It loads all many-one etc relations because we have only three types of FetchModes i.e Select, Proxy and Default and in all these cases it loads many-one (may be i am wrong if so help me out :))

2nd issue with Criteria is that it loads complete object i.e if i want to just load EmpName of an employee it wont come up with this insted it come up with complete Employee object and i can get EmpName from it due to this **it really work bad in reporting**. where as HQL just load(did't load association/relations) what u want so increase performance many times.

One feature of Criteria is that it will safe u from SQL Injection because of its dynamic query generation where as in HQL as ur queries are either fixed or parameterised so are not safe from SQL Injection.

Also if you write HQL in ur aspx.cs files, then you are tightly coupled with ur DAL.

Overall my conclusion is that there are places where u can't live without HQL like reports so use them else Criteria is more easy to manage.

Comment: HQL is NOT SQL injection safe

Comment: I think Criteria is not injection safe. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746486/how-to-secure-hibernate-qbe-query

Comment: HQL IS sql injection safe by adding 'setParameter'

Comment: @Zafar: you can select only certain properties of an entity using projections

Comment: @Zafar you can set projection in criteria query to select particular columns. You can fetch EmpName, no need to fetch complete object.

Answer (score 12):

For me the biggest win on Criteria is the Example API, where you can pass an object and hibernate will build a query based on those object properties.

Besides that, the criteria API has its quirks (I believe the hibernate team is reworking the api), like:

- a criteria.createAlias("obj") forces a inner join instead of a possible outer join
- you can't create the same alias two times
- some sql clauses have no simple criteria counterpart (like a subselect)
- etc.

I tend to use HQL when I want queries similar to sql (delete from Users where status='blocked'), and I tend to use criteria when I don't want to use string appending.

Another advantage of HQL is that you can define all your queries before hand, and even externalise them to a file or so.

Answer (score 9):

We used mainly Criteria in our application in the beginning but after it was replaced with HQL due to the performance issues. 
Mainly we are using very complex queries with several joins which leads to multiple queries in Criteria but is very optimized in HQL. 
The case is that we use just several propeties on specific object and not complete objects. With Criteria the problem was also string concatenation. 
Let say if you need to display name and surname of the user in HQL it is quite easy `(name || ' ' || surname)` but in Crteria this is not possible. 
To overcome this we used ResultTransormers, where there were methods where such concatenation was implemented for needed result. 
Today we mainly use HQL like this:

```
String hql = "select " +
            "c.uuid as uuid," +
            "c.name as name," +
            "c.objective as objective," +
            "c.startDate as startDate," +
            "c.endDate as endDate," +
            "c.description as description," +
            "s.status as status," +
            "t.type as type " +
            "from " + Campaign.class.getName() + " c " +
            "left join c.type t " +
            "left join c.status s";

Query query =  hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getSession(EntityMode.MAP).createQuery(hql);
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
return query.list();
```

so in our case the returned records are maps of needed properties.

Comment: With Criteria you can to use org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP

Comment: Returning a list of maps in my experience has a very bad performance. I prefer to return a list of object arrays or a lists of beans (you can always define a bean that suits your specific result set).

Answer (score 9):

Criteria api provide one distinct feature that Neither SQL or HQL provides. ie. it allows compile time checking of a query.

Answer (score 7):

Criteria query for dynamically we can construct query based on our inputs..In case of Hql query is the static query once we construct we can't change the structure of the query.

Comment: Not so. With HQL you can set properties with the ':' identifier, and then replace those properties with unique values. For example, Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT :aValue FROM my_table"); and then q.setParameter("aValue", "some_column_name");

Comment: @MattC In your example you're changing parameters' values, not the structure of the query.

Answer (score 7):

- HQL is to perform both select and non-select operations on the data,  but Criteria is only for selecting the data, we cannot perform non-select operations using criteria
- HQL is suitable for executing Static Queries, where as Criteria is suitable for executing Dynamic Queries
- HQL doesn’t support pagination concept, but we can achieve pagination with Criteria
- Criteria used to take more time to execute then HQL
- With Criteria we are safe with SQL Injection because of its dynamic query generation but in HQL as your queries are either fixed or parametrized, there is no safe from SQL Injection.

[source](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/difference-between-hql-and-criteria-query-in-hibernate/)

Comment: To clarify, criteria queries using Hibernate's Criteria API may be available for querying, but JPA criteria queries cover selects, updates, and deletions.  See `CriteriaUpdate<T>` and `CriteriaDelete<T>` for reference.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to kick a dead horse here, but it is important to mention that Criteria queries are now deprecated. Use HQL.

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer Criteria Queries for dynamic queries. But I prefer hql for delete queries, for example if delete all records from child table for parent id 'xyz', It is easily achieved by HQL, but for criteria API first we must fire n number of delete query where n is number of child table records.

Answer (score 0):

Most the answers here are misleading and mention that `Criteria Queries` are slower than `HQL`, which is actually not the case.

If you delve deep and perform some tests you will see ***Criteria Queries perform much better that regular HQL***.

And also with **Criteria Query** you get *Object Oriented control* which is not there with **HQL**.

For more information read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770549/1475228).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. I ended up with creating a HQL parser based on hibernate original syntax so it first parse the HQL then it could dynamically inject dynamic parameters or automatically adding some common filters for the HQL queries. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old.  Most answers talk about Hibernate criteria, not JPA criteria. JPA 2.1 added CriteriaDelete/CriteriaUpdate, and EntityGraph that controls what exactly to fetch. Criteria API is better since Java is OO. That is why JPA is created. When JPQL is compiled, it will be translated to AST tree(OO model) before translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another point is that, I see Criteria is more suited for building on top of it and not to be used ditectly in the end-code.

It is more suited to build liberaries using it more than using jpql or hql.

For example I've build [spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions](https://github.com/mhewedy/spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions) using Criteria API (the same way spring data QBE do).

> I think spring data query generations are using jpaql rather criteria which I don't understand why.

Answer (score -3):

HQL can cause **security** concerns like SQL injection.

Comment: These issues are not caused by HQL, but by the lack of understanding of basic software development practices. I can create code prone to sql injection attacks with criteria api just as well.

Comment: It's like saying "querying an RDBMS from Java can cause SQL injection security concerns" :D