# Difference between HQL and Criteria Query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate: Criteria vs. HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql)

There are HQL Query and Criteria Query in Hibernate. I just wanna that which will be used in which scenario? And what are advantages and disadvantages over each other?

Thanks,

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql)

Answer (score 0):

HQL Query is similar sql query using object and their attributes. It is a `string`, so the you don't if it is correct until runtime. Criteria query is less error prone.