# How to secure Hibernate QBE query

Tags: java, hibernate, query-by-example

By the moment, I know four kinds of doing transactions with hibernate:

1. Using objects
2. Using HQL
3. Using DB-specific SQL
4. Using criteria (QBE)

Well, regarding how strong are they against injections, I think these are (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Secure, because the internal SQL call is parameterized.
2. Secure if the query is parameterized, insecure otherwise.
3. Same as #2 but not as portable.
4. Insecure?

My question is about #4, Query by Example, because i've found it is also vulnerable. Example:

```
    Account a = new Account(); //POJO class       
    a.setId("1' OR '1'='1");

    //s is a org.hibernate.Session instance
    Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(Account.class);
    crit.add(Example.create(a));
    List results = crit.list();  //table dump!
```

That snippet selects the whole accounts table. Is there any way to prevent injection? How?

NOTE: I'm using Hibernate 3.6.5 final, the testing database is HSQLDB.

UPDATE: Seems like a bug to me too, and indeed may be not related to the injected SQL. Tried setting the id with a nonexistent value and also returns all the rows. Tried the injection with '5'='5' instead of '1'='1' and the 5 is not propagated to the SQL call. It keeps using (1=1) as where clause.

UPDATE 2: Solved. See the answer below.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. You should probably post that to hibernate. In general HQL/SQL parameterization is the way to go (IMHO).

Comment: @Adam Gent I know it is possible to do the same with HQL, but QBE is less verbose, and you don't have to check the nullity of the fields you're not interested in.

Comment: I see your point but I still prefer HQL as I am used to SQL and so are the others I work with (hence the IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate QBE ignores the id (mapped to PK) fields. Seems that this is done because an id filter would return only a row, and this can be achieved with a get() or a load(). I wonder what if I want to use a like condition on the id???

Related posts on hibernate official forum:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=927063

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=938036

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize your input E.g. in your code you should make sure you set a Long value to the ID field.