# Fetch results from session.load using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to fetch resultset by making the query in Hibernate like

```
String id = "10";   
Person per = session.load(Person .class, id); // This is wrong, because it accepts only an integer, not a string.
```

But, I require to fetch results using session.load by passing a string, because second level cache is not triggering when I try to fetch as

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.like("userId", id));
List<?> results = cr.list();
```

### Person class

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Personalisation [id=" + id + ", userId=" + userId
            + ", courseId=" + courseId + ", courseValue=" + courseValue
            + "]";
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String userId;
private String courseId;
private String courseValue;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}
public void setCourseId(String courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}
public String getCourseValue() {
    return courseValue;
}
public void setCourseValue(String courseValue) {
    this.courseValue = courseValue;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
```

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intu</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

<!-- Ehcache config -->          
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>

<!-- c3p0 Connection pool config -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource">library</property>



<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<mapping class="com.intu.Dashboard" />
<mapping class="com.intu.Employee"/>
<mapping class="com.intu.Person"/>
```

The above code is working, but not by second level cache, each time its hitting DB.

What steps do I need to do to get it done? Is there any other way

Comment: can you post the `Person` class and hibernate configuration file?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, updated with person class

Comment: Since person id is of type int, Try with `int id = 10;` instead `String id = "10"`; .Also please post hibernate configuration file.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, it would be a string type only. I can't try with int, because it may have even "s10", alpha numeric too.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, updated with hibernate cfg file

Comment: please call `cr.setCacheable(true)` and try.

Comment: no issues. Add that line after `cr.add(Restrictions.like("userId", id));` will move to chat, if needed.

Comment: Ye ye..... Awesome. It worked. Please post that in answer. I will accept.

Comment: By the way, is it better to use Query or Criteria to fetch the result? Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107093/discussion-between-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu-and-syed).

Comment: No problem. This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call `cr.setCacheable(true)` after `cr.add(Restrictions.like("userId", id))`.