# Hibernate HQL compare timestamp to null

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL and I would like to know how it handles comparing date column to null. For example what happens in case the **givenTime** parameter is null. I checked and got empty results. Is it always the case? is it documented?

```
select mo from MyClassMO mo
where mo.creationDate is not null and mo.creationDate >= (:givenTime)
```

and what if the **givenTime** replaced with inner select query which returns null?
thanks

Comment: if givenTime is NULL you must manage manually.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about hql but for handling such a cases I prefer using something called Criteria in hibernate. It can be mixed up easy with SQL.

[JPA and Hibernate - Criteria vs. JPQL or HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql?rq=1)

```
Criteria criteria = session
            .createCriteria(MyClassMO.class)
               .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("creationDate"));
if (givenTime!=null){
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("creationDate", givenTime));//ge - greater equals
}
List<MyClassMO> result = criteria.list();
```

Comment: and what if the givenTime replaced with inner select query which returns null?

Answer (score -1):

If your parameter is nullable, you must manage it manually.

In base of your applied logic, you can write the query.

I suppose some cases (tell me if your is one of these or another).

**Case 1: Not consider givenTime in filter**

You can wirte this query:

```
String hql = "select mo from MyClassMO mo" + 
     " where mo.creationDate is not null";

if (givenTime != null) {
    hql += " and mo.creationDate >= (:givenTime)";
}
```

**Case 2: if givenTime is null, put the current date**

```
String hql = "select mo from MyClassMO mo" + 
    " where mo.creationDate is not null " +
    " and mo.creationDate >= COALESCE(:givenTime, current_date())";
```

**Case 3: if givenTime is in subquery returns null, put the current date**

```
String hql = "select mo from MyClassMO mo" + 
    " where mo.creationDate is not null " +
    " and mo.creationDate >= "
    " (SELECT COALESCE(:giventime, current_date()) " +
    "  FROM yourtable WHERE conditions";
```

Comment: and what if the givenTime replaced with inner select query which returns null?

Comment: If the givenTime is NULL with coalesce you'll get the current date.