# Spring Data JPA CriteriaBuilder vs JPQL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I'm thinking what better to use in the project for implementing custom methods. I'm using Spring Data JPA and now I see 2 ways:

- CriteriaBuilder;
- JPQL;

What is better for performance, project support?

Comment: You use one or the other depending on the use case. JPQL for static queries. Criteria for dynamically created queries based on various... criteria. Performance is irrelevant.

Comment: Is SQL also a choice?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/341440/2387977

Comment: Hey @LukasEder , SQL and HQL are always a choice.